# Access Database error:: “No value given for one or more required parameters.”

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datagridview, oledbdatareader

I have a datagridview. In this DGV first colum is a combobox column. I want to make, when this combobox value is selected next fild will be filled automatically from database. But there shows a error.

> No value given for one or more required parameters on
>   OleDbDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

I post the code. Please help me.

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conn);
con.Open();

for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
{

    string query = "select Description from General where AccCode='" +
        dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value +
        "' and conpanyID='" +
        label1.Text + "'";
    OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
    //OleDbDataAdapter daBranchName = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    OleDbDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr1.Read())
    {
        dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dr1["Description"].ToString();
    }
}
con.Close();
```

Comment: This can't be the code you're executing when getting this error. It's just not possible. There are no parameters in the query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This kind of string concatenations are open for *[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)* attacks.

Use *[parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)* instead.

```
string query = "select [Description] from [General] where AccCode= ? and conpanyID= ?";
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acc", dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", label1.Text);
```

As HansUp [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720764/access-database-error-no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-parameters/18720822?noredirect=1#comment27586002_18720822), `Description` and `General` are *[reserved keywords](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#D)*. Use them with square brackets like `[Description]` and `[General]`

Comment: `Description` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#D).  Bracket that name in the SQL statement: `SELECT [Description] FROM ...`

Comment: Also double-check `conpanyID` vs. `companyID` as Lars suggested.

Comment: You're welcome, Soner.  I didn't notice at first, but `General` is also a reserved word.  Apparently that one didn't create a problem in this case.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested, use parameterized queries.

As far as the error is concerned, I'm guessing this field name is wrong:

```
conpanyID=
```

should be:

```
companyID=
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Parameters, otherwise it will open for sql injection attacks.

```
string query = "select [Description] from General where AccCode=? and conpanyID=?";
```

now you can set parameters

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", val1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", val2);
```

Comment: @AnimeshGhosh do you have columns called `AccCode` and `conpanyID` in your `General` table? what are the column types in database for those?

Comment: @AnimeshGhosh use `[]` for `Description` as my updated answer