# VB.Net: No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, parameters, basic

I am trying to create a Library Management system in VB (Visual Basic 2010).

I have a DataGridView called DataGridViewLoans which is meant to show the current loans for a reader. It is in a seperate form to the main window, and when the form loads the readers ID is passed to the form.

I want it (DataGridViewLoans) to show the current loans for the reader, with the books Title.

I have created a SQL query in Access, and included this into the code. However, when I run the program it says: No value given for one or more required parameters.

I have tried various different ways but it always gives the same error.

The program gives the error on the "dAdapter.Fill(dataTable)" line.

Here is the code I have:

```
Dim connectionString As String = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = C:\Documents and Settings\Timothy\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\LibraryManagementSystemPrototype\Database\library.mdb;"
    Dim query As String = "SELECT Catalogue.Number, Catalogue.Title, Catalogue.Author, Catalogue.ID, Loans.[Issue Date], Loans.[Date Due], Loans.Overdue, Loans.[Days Overdue], Loans.ID_ENROLMENT, Loans.ID_CATALOGUE FROM Catalogue INNER JOIN Loans ON Catalogue.ID = Loans.ID_CATALOGUE WHERE (((Catalogue.ID)=[Loans].[ID_CATALOGUE]) AND ((Loans.ID_ENROLMENT)=[Enrolment].[ID]));"

    Dim dAdapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(query, connectionString)
    Dim cBuilder As OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(dAdapter)

    Dim dataTable As New DataTable()

    dAdapter.Fill(dataTable)

    Dim bindingSource As New BindingSource()
    bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable

    DataGridViewLoans.DataSource = bindingSource
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your query returns values?

Comment: Usually this happens when you have one or more typos in your field or table names

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720764/access-database-error-no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when you have one or more typos in your field or table names, but in this case you have totally missed the join on the Enrolment table. You have it in your where but nowhere in the FROM/JOIN part

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT Catalogue.Number, Catalogue.Title, " & _ 
   "Catalogue.Author, Catalogue.ID, Loans.[Issue Date], Loans.[Date Due], " & _ 
   "Loans.Overdue, Loans.[Days Overdue], Loans.ID_ENROLMENT, Loans.ID_CATALOGUE " & _
   "FROM Catalogue INNER JOIN Loans ON Catalogue.ID = Loans.ID_CATALOGUE " & _
   "INNER JOIN Enrolment ON Enrolment.ID = Loans.ID_Enrolment"
```

As you could see, the WHERE part is unnecessary