# Referencing an entire data set instead of a single Cell

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a login form for users to log into using a database. I was wondering if there is a way in which i could get the program to search the entire table instead of a certain item. Here is my code so far.

```
Dim UserInputtedUsername As String
    Dim UserInputtedPassword As String

    UserInputtedUsername = txtAdminUsername.Text
    UserInputtedPassword = txtAdminPassword.Text

    sqlrunnerQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblLogin"
    daRunners = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlrunnerQuery, RunnerConnection)
    daRunners.Fill(dsRunner, "Login")
    If UserInputtedUsername = dsadminlogin.Tables("Login").Rows(0).Item(2) And UserInputtedPassword = dsadminlogin.Tables("Login").Rows(0).Item(3) Then
        Form1.Show()
    ElseIf MsgBox("You have entered incorrect details") Then
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: change the SQL query to use a WHERE clause.  you will only get a row back if it matches that Name ad PW (which should be hashed, BTW).

Comment: Please don't store passwords in plain-text. Learn how to hash and salt them.

Answer (score 1):

Instead if searching the (in-memory) `DataSet` for your user serach the database in the first place. Therefore you have to use a `WHERE` in the sql query(with guessed column names):

```
sqlrunnerQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblLogin WHERE UserName=@UserName AND PassWord=@PassWord"
```

Note that i've used sql-parameters to prevent sql-injection. You add them in this way:

```
daRunners = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlrunnerQuery, RunnerConnection)
daRunners.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtAdminUsername.Text)
daRunners.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PassWord", txtAdminPassword.Text)
```

Now the table is empty if there is no such user.

```
If dsadminlogin.Tables("Login").Rows.Count = 0  Then
    MsgBox("You have entered incorrect details")
End If
```

For the sake of completeteness, you can search a complete `DataTable` with [`DataTable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx). But i prefer [LINQ-To-DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Here's a simple example:

```
Dim grishamBooks = From bookRow in tblBooks
                   Where bookRow.Field(Of String)("Author") = "John Grisham"
Dim weHaveGrisham = grishamBooks.Any()
```

Comment: The collumn names are UserUsername and UserPassword. How would i set it out if this were the case

Comment: @JoelHumphreys: with the database- or the `DataTable` approach(less efficient)? I've already shown the sql way, if you want to filter the `DataSet`/`DataTable`: `Dim user=From row In dsadminlogin.Tables("Login") Where row.Field(Of String)("UserUsername")=txtAdminUsername.Text AndAlso row.Field(Of String)("UserPassword")=txtAdminPassword.Text`

Comment: hi tim. i Have followed all your steps above but it is providing me of an error that there is no value in required parameters on the line,  daRunners.Fill(dsRunner, "Login") Any ideas? This is for the SQL Way.

Comment: @JoelHumphreys: have you seen that i've edited my comment? What database are you using at all? The way how you pass the parameters differs. In SQL-Server and most others you need to use the syntax above("@UserName").  Have you used `daRunners.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue` (or `Parameters.Add`)?

Comment: Yes i have used daRunners.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue i am running through an access database.

Comment: @JoelHumphreys: normally that should work also in Access, but then the column order is important and must match the order you add the parameters. Have a look here, you can try to use the question mark: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720764/access-database-error-no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-parameters