# this code returns an error that says " No value given for one or more required parameters"

Tags: c#

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clss.Connect();
    clss.search("select * from Employee E, AssetAllocation A WHERE E.EmployeeID=6 and A.EmployeeID=6");
    //, where E.EmployeeID=" + textBox12.Text + " and A.EmployeeID=" + textBox12.Text + "");
    while (clss.reader.Read())
    {
        textBox11.Text = clss.reader["Department"].ToString();
        textBox10.Text = clss.reader["Emp_Name"].ToString();
        textBox9.Text = clss.reader["OfficeNumber"].ToString();
        listBox1.Items.Add(clss.reader["AllocationDate"].ToString());
    }

    clss.reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is `clss`? On what line of code do you get the exception?

Comment: What is the type of `clss`? On what row does the error occur? What DBMS is it?

Comment: For the sql itself - why not use a `join`? `select * from Employee E join AssetAllocation A on E.EmployeeId = A.EmployeeId where E.EmployeeId = 6`

Comment: Where exactly is your error being thrown, did you try debug your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Database error:: “No value given for one or more required parameters.”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720764/access-database-error-no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-parameters)

Comment: The select query has no parameters and the connect clss has not parameters added.  The parameters are ["Department"], ["Emp_Name"], ...

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify what clss exactly is... Otherwise my only solution is doing this:

Make sure you are not missing any parameters for example:

```
public class Employee {
    public Employee(string Name) {
       // Some Code Here
    }
}
```

To me clss looks like that but not named Employee and most likely has different arguments. So for the example below it shows that i want to create a new object from the Employee class, and it shows which one triggers the error and which one doesn't.

> Employee karen = new Employee(); // Triggers the Error
>
> Employee karen = new Employee("Karen"); // Doesn't Trigger Error

I am sorry if this does not help you, Or it is not actually going to work as i suppose. This is the first time I've tried to answer a question. And it's been a while since I've stopped coding in C#.